# Download file from field instead of going to node page

Tags: files

What I'm trying to achieve is: create a new content of type arquivo, then when accessing the new content url, instead of showing a page with the fields and etc., the file from a field_file is opened/downloaded. Tried to achieve this using a custom template for the content type with no success.
The code for the tpl.php is:

```
<?php
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_arquivo');
$filepath = $items[1]['uri'];
$path = file_create_url($filepath);
drupal_goto($path); 
?>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a custom module and put this function in it

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function custom_tweaks_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'arquivo' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    $file = $node->field_file[$langcode][0]['uri'];
    if ($file) {
      $file_uri = file_create_url($file);
      drupal_goto($file_uri);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the function with a check if there is a file present on the node and to only redirect when the full node is being displayed.

Comment: A simple change that would make it more portable is changing `'und'` for `$langcode`. In case anyone is dealing with a site with multiple languages.

Comment: But ofcourse. I updated the code @rovr138.